# How can I automate logging into a website that requires cookies in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to log into a website (https://prudential.com/login) to automatically scrape my account balance every day to build up historical data for a pet project.

I am able to get the content I want by logging in to my own account, checking the developer console and copying the endpoint url. My headers are user agent, content type, and cookies - if I don't include cookies, the requests go through but the json is nonexistent. The second I logout, the cookie is invalid and the code doesn't work: request 200 but no json.

I know that I'll likely need to start a requests session. How do I view the elements for what I should call the keys in the payload (e.g. username, password), which payload keys I need, and which cookie do I need?

Additionally, what happens if the website is expecting me to input a security message if it doesn't recognize the computer? This happens occasionally if I login from a different device.

I have tried using Selenium, but I would often get a Captcha I don't know how to recover from. I am able to make a request when I am logged in, the issue is how I log in and how do I get the cookie needed to make the request?

Answer (score 0):

one way I can think of using selenium and in case you get the captcha(assuming character based), capture the screenshot of it and extract the characters using   **[ddddocr](https://pypi.org/project/ddddocr/)**

```
captcha = driver.find_element(By.ID, "......") # find the captcha either by Xpath, Id or whichever works
captcha.screenshot(f'captcha_{i}.png')
ocr = ddddocr.DdddOcr()
with open(f'captcha_{i}.png', 'rb') as f:
    img_bytes = f.read()

res = ocr.classification(img_bytes)
```

"res" will get the content of the captcha, then you can fill it to proceed with login.

This way you will be able to login with captcha and can scrap the details from your account. But This solution will only work if it's character based captcha (either digits or letters or mix of both).